# How to call constructor without new?

Tags: c#, constructor

i know that string is like a class, and when creating a new string the string itself doesnt owe the value but only the value's pointer. but when creating a string there is no need to use the word new;

```
string a = "hello";
```

and not

```
string a = new string("hello");
```

I know that the second option is also possible but what i want to understand is why the first one?

Let's say I have a class name student which he's constructor gets a `string`. To create a new class I must use the saved word new.

```
student example = new student("Sabrina");
```

I tried overload `oparator =` but it is not possible.

How can I create a new class like a `string` does (without using the word `new`)?

```
student example = "Sabrina";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use cast operator to implicitly:

```
    sealed class Student
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        Student()
        {
        }

        public static implicit operator Student(string name)
        {
            return new Student
            {
                Name = name
            };
        }
    }
```

Then you can do `Student student = "Sabrina";`.

Comment: +1. Note that `string` uses different mechanism  - special case (similar to `int`...) implemented in compiler, which is not available to users to extend.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov. While this looks like it "works", there are very good reasons not to do it. For example, `Student a = "John Doe";` and `Student b = "John Doe";` will result in two different objects that do not compare with the Object.Equals method. You would have to override the equals method for `Student`, but that is just further obfuscating the problem.

Comment: yes you're totally right, i simple give a way to do what he want.

Comment: Also, what really happens when you do `Student student = "Sabrina";` is that an instance of `string` is created through this "magic" that the original poster wants to know about, then a reference to that `string` object is passed to the `implicit operator` method in the body of which a `Student` instance is created with ... the `new` keyword! So this is a kind of cheating. The real answer is that the class `string` is treated in a very special way by both the C# syntax and the Common Language Runtime. So you can't write your own class that acts like `string`.

Comment: Yes string, like int, byte etc. are treated a little different. The point to me is more pratically. It's a bad idea to do this because that can give more than a problem if you work with a team.

Answer (score 6):

The string `"hello"` in your code, in all cases, does not involve a call to a constructor. It is a constant value, created at compile time, such that all instances of the string `"hello"` are all the same object. Similarly, the integer `1` and decimal value `3.456`, and any other "literal" value, are constants that exist before runtime, before the constructor code can have a chance to be called.

The code `new string("hello");` cannot be called, as there is no constructor for string that takes a string as a value. However, if you changed it to `new string("hello".ToCharArray());`, you would get a string object, but it won't be the same thing as the string `"hello"`. You've actually created a new string, at a separate memory location, from just plain `"hello"`. It only just so happens to have the same character values contained in it as `"hello"`.

The significance is that, if you do use the implicit type conversion trick, then one string literal converted to your type will not be the same object:

```
class Foo
{
    private string value;
    public Foo(string val)
    {
        this.value = val;
    }
    public static implicit operator Foo(string value)
    {
        return new Foo(value);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Foo a = "asdf";
        Foo b = "asdf";
        Assert.AreNotEqual(a, b);
    }
}
```

In other words, `a.Equals(b)` returns false. In order to make the Equals method return true, you'll have to override the Equals method in your Foo class.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Foo && value.Equals(((Foo)obj).value);
}
```

But, as mentioned by other posters, this is an obfuscation. You'll make it difficult to use the code as well as difficult to debug it. It changes what looks like a regular assignment to a full method call. And it breaks many of the tools that Visual Studio provides for inspecting code, such as F12 to jump to a method definition.

Implicit type conversion should be used only in cases where the two types are actually quite interchangeable in use, with minor differences in their functionality. The `float` type can implicitly convert to `double` because there are no extra methods and functions for `double` vs `float`, and increasing the precision from `float` to `double` does not change the value. However, going from `double` to `float` requires an explicit cast, because the loss of precision changes the value represented.

Answer (score 6):

Although you *can* get this done using an `implicit operator`, I would highly recommend not doing this at all. `Strings` are special animals in C# and they get special treatment - along with other special classes like `int` and `float`, you can create them without explicitly `new`ing them up due to the way the C# compiler works:

```
var myInt = 0;
var myFloat = 0f;
var myString = "string";
```

However, this behavior is typically restricted to those special classes. Adding an `implicit operator` to do this is bad practice for multiple reasons:

- **It hides what is actually going on underneath.** Are we creating a `new Student` under the hood when converting from a `string`?
- **It is unmaintainable.** What happens when you have to add another parameter to the constructor to include the `Student`'s ID number as well?
- **It eliminates the possibility of using implicitly-typed variables.** You can't call `var student = "name"`; you *must* call `Student student = "name"`.

The `implicit operator` paradigm breaks down very quickly. Though it's a cool thing to do, you're setting yourself up for a bad time down the road and making your code more difficult to read. I would highly advise just using `new Student("name")` like all other normal objects in C#.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I was thinking while writing the answer.

Comment: I agree that it would be a bad idea in this situation, but there are legitimate uses for implicit operator (the BCL has quite a few examples of that, e.g. in Linq to XML)

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely *many* legitimate uses for them. I would argue that this is not one though.

Comment: Implicit type conversion should be used only in cases where the two types are actually quite interchangeable in use, with minor differences in their functionality. The `float` type can implicitly convert to `double` because there are no extra methods and functions for `double` vs `float`, and increasing the precision from `float` to `double` does not change the value. However, going from `double` to `float` requires an explicit cast, because the loss of precision changes the value represented.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method named createObject() and use that while having the constructors private, discourage their use.

Comment: What real, actionable difference is there between a `Foo.createFoo()` and `new Foo()` other than a few characters? It doesn't change the paradigm at all, and ultimate just breaks common, expected usage patterns.